# How to correctly resample time series data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have time series data on a PostgreSQL database. Currently I import this into pandas to do some analysis and my first step often times is resampling the 5 min frequency data to 1 hour average data. I do this so that I first pivot the data to bring it in wide form, then I resample it to 1 hour and after that I melt it to have it in long form again.

Now I want to do the resampling on the Database so that I can import the 1 hour average right away.

This is what the data looks like on the Database. I have two different types with 3 different names.

```
    datetime                    value   type   name
0    2018-01-01 13:35:00+01:00   0.22    HLN    NO2
1    2018-01-01 13:35:00+01:00   0.31    HLN    CO
2    2018-01-01 13:35:00+01:00   1.15    HLN    NO
3    2018-01-01 13:40:00+01:00   1.80    AIS    NO2
4    2018-01-01 13:40:00+01:00   2.60    AIS    CO
5    2018-01-01 13:40:00+01:00   2.30    AIS    NO
6    2018-01-01 13:45:00+01:00   2.25    HLN    NO2
7    2018-01-01 13:45:00+01:00   2.14    HLN    CO
8    2018-01-01 13:45:00+01:00   2.96    HLN    NO
9    2018-01-01 14:35:00+01:00   0.76    HLN    NO2
10   2018-01-01 14:35:00+01:00   0.80    HLN    CO
11   2018-01-01 14:35:00+01:00   1.19    HLN    NO
12   2018-01-01 14:40:00+01:00   1.10    AIS    NO2
13   2018-01-01 14:40:00+01:00   2.87    AIS    CO
14   2018-01-01 14:40:00+01:00   2.80    AIS    NO
15   2018-01-01 14:45:00+01:00   3.06    HLN    NO2
16   2018-01-01 13:45:00+01:00   2.86    HLN    CO
17   2018-01-01 13:45:00+01:00   2.22    HLN    NO
```

Now comes the part which I have problems with. After resampling and plotting it in pandas and plotly I get the expected result which is right, one value for every hour:

[image]

After performing a SQL Query to resample it to one hour with the following code:

```
SELECT date_trunc('hour', datetime) AS hour, type, AVG(value) AS measure, name
                    FROM data_table
                    GROUP BY datetime, type, name
                    ORDER BY datetime
```

I get this after plotting:

[image]

This is not smooth and there are multiple values in the hour, I guess there are all the values within the hour.

My question, how can I correctly resample a time series in SQL?

Edit: Expected result in table form:

```
 datetime             value  type  name
2018-01-01 13:00:00   1.235   HLN   NO2
2018-01-01 13:00:00   2.65   HLN   CO
2018-01-01 13:00:00   2.96   HLN   NO
2018-01-01 13:00:00   2.48   AIS   NO2
2018-01-01 13:00:00   2.65   AIS   CO
2018-01-01 13:00:00   2.26   AIS   NO
2018-01-01 14:00:00   2.78   HLN   NO2
2018-01-01 14:00:00   3.65   HLN   CO
2018-01-01 14:00:00   1.95   HLN   NO
2018-01-01 14:00:00   1.45   AIS   NO2
2018-01-01 14:00:00   1.64   AIS   CO
2018-01-01 14:00:00   3.23   AIS   NO
```

Comment: Your query looks fine. Can you add the expected result?

Comment: @JimJones the expected result is the first picture.

Comment: I meant the exact expected result set as text/table :) PostgreSQL does not plot a graph itself :)

Comment: @JimJones I added the expected result. Right know it is fabricated, since the original database is to big right now to handle it for me.

Comment: can you check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3276fc2cafe09efa46e3af0a6db0276e)?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to create the time intervals using `generate_series()` or just with in a subquery / CTE truncate the hours per `type` and `name`, and in the outer query join both records and aggregate the `values` with `avg()` by the columns `hour`, `type` and `name`, e.g.

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT date_trunc('hour', datetime) AS hour, type,name 
  FROM data_table
)
SELECT j.*, avg(d.value)
FROM data_table d
JOIN j ON date_trunc('hour', d.datetime) = j.hour AND 
          j.type = d.type AND 
          d.name = j.name
GROUP BY j.hour, j.name, j.type
ORDER BY j.hour ASC,j.type DESC;

        hour         | type | name |          avg           
---------------------+------+------+------------------------
 2018-01-01 13:00:00 | HLN  | CO   |     1.7700000000000000
 2018-01-01 13:00:00 | HLN  | NO   |     2.1100000000000000
 2018-01-01 13:00:00 | HLN  | NO2  | 1.23500000000000000000
 2018-01-01 13:00:00 | AIS  | CO   |     2.6000000000000000
 2018-01-01 13:00:00 | AIS  | NO   |     2.3000000000000000
 2018-01-01 13:00:00 | AIS  | NO2  | 1.80000000000000000000
 2018-01-01 14:00:00 | HLN  | CO   | 0.80000000000000000000
 2018-01-01 14:00:00 | HLN  | NO   | 1.19000000000000000000
 2018-01-01 14:00:00 | HLN  | NO2  |     1.9100000000000000
 2018-01-01 14:00:00 | AIS  | CO   |     2.8700000000000000
 2018-01-01 14:00:00 | AIS  | NO   |     2.8000000000000000
 2018-01-01 14:00:00 | AIS  | NO2  | 1.10000000000000000000
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=416ab5dfad2dda56d5015fa492070d31)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I found the mistake in my code. I need to insert `date_trunc('hour', datetime)` both in GROUP BY and ORDER BY instead of datetime. Now it works as expected.

Comment: @Gobrel nice you solved it. +1 for the feedback :) feel free to edit my answer (or post your own) with the corrected query, so that other users my also profit from it. cheers and happy coding.